# Integrate $\int \frac{x^7}{(1-x^4)^2}dx$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{x^7}{(1-x^4)^2}dx$$

I have tried to simplify the expression, to use U substation, any idea where to start from?

Comment: $u = \frac{1}{1-x^4}$

Comment: What is U substation, or substitution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$\dfrac14\int\dfrac{x^4}{(1-x^4)^2}\cdot4x^3\ dx$$

Set $1-x^4=u$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{x^7}{\left(1-x^4\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\frac{x^7}{\left(x^4-1\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=x^4$ and $\text{d}u=4x^3\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{u}{\left(u-1\right)^2}\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\int\left[\frac{1}{u-1}+\frac{1}{(u-1)^2}\right]\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\left[\int\frac{1}{u-1}\space\text{d}u+\int\frac{1}{(u-1)^2}\space\text{d}u\right]=$$

---

Substitute $s=u-1$ and $\text{d}s=\text{d}u$:

---

$$\frac{1}{4}\left[\int\frac{1}{s}\space\text{d}s+\int\frac{1}{s^2}\space\text{d}s\right]=$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left|s\right|-\frac{1}{s}\right]+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left|u-1\right|-\frac{1}{u-1}\right]+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left|x^4-1\right|-\frac{1}{x^4-1}\right]+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left|x^4-1\right|+\frac{1}{1-x^4}\right]+\text{C}$$